# Can't find a device on my network

Tags: ipv4, networking, ssh

I have a device on my network that is at a static address (192.168.3.1). This device is connected to a network switch, that is also connected to the rest of my network. My problem is that I need to be able to find that device on the network, to run some software/ssh/etc. When I connect my laptop directly into the switch and set a static IP (192.168.3.200), I can find that device and do what I need, but then I don't have internet. Here is a crude drawing of what my problem is. Where Device 1 has the static IP, and Device 2 doesn't. I can find Device 2 on my network.

[image]

Device 1 also has a specific DNS and subnet mask if that matters. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With a managed switch, you could look at its MAC table and follow the cable. However, consumer-grade hardware and host configurations/issues are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. You might want to try on [su].

Comment: Hey this is for business though thanks for your help.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to mix different networks on the same LAN. Your DHCP is giving devices one network, but you are statically assigning devices to a different network. It takes a router to route packets between networks, and the router needs to know how to reach each network.

Comment: @Will I'm sorry, but consumer-grade devices (as you seem to use) are just as off topic here. You know that you can configure multiple IP addresses/subnets on a single NIC, don't you?

Comment: @RonMaupin The device in question (Device 1) has a cellular/wifi card in it, so in a production environment it bridges its internet to Device 2. Also probably about the DHCP but i'm not 100% sure, I am not a network engineer, I am a software engineer, so this is a bit out of my wheel house.

Comment: @Zac67 The device in question is not a consumer-grade device, it is something like a telematic control unit.

Comment: You cannot bridge networks, you must route between them. Bridging will forward frames on the same network, but routing forwards packets between networks. You put separate networks on different VLANs on the switch. In any case, we would need a lot more information, such as the network device models, the network device configurations, any logs, debugs, etc. We cannot guess or speculate about where you went wrong.

Comment: I want to be able to ssh from my laptop into Device 1 at that specific ip address (192.168.3.1), Device 2 also has a specific IP address on that network (192.168.3.100). I may need to revise my image, the two devices are connected via the switch and create a network via the static IPs they have, and the laptop and modem are on a separate network, w/ addresses 192.168.0.*. Do I need a router between the normal network and the other device network to be able to ssh at that static IP?

Comment: I edited my image to be more clear.

Comment: You seem to have a host configuration problem, and that is off-topic here. You could try to ask about that on [sf] for a business network, but they will want you to follow reasonable business network practices. You will also need to provide network device models and configurations as we need here.

Comment: I think there's a language disconnect here. The word you need is "reach" or "connect to", not "find". As an English speaking network engineer, "find" means "go put your hands on it". As Zac eventually reached, you need an additional network interface to connect to this isolated network without disconnecting from the existing one. (most modern OSes allow one interface to have multiple addresses, but not with DHCP enabled.)

Comment: So, you can actually assign more than 1 IP address to a network interface.  If you configure the IP on the NIC as 192.168.0.x and then add a secondary address of 192.168.3.x (and DON'T add a default gateway on that one), then you would be able to access both the "normal" network and the "device" network at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, (I think) I understand your question: you have two networks and want to connect to both of them simultaneously with laptop, correct?

If you add a second (USB) NIC to the laptop you can directly connect to the left-hand network. That is the easiest method.

Another option is to connect both networks with a router. That requires all relevant nodes to be configured to use the router as gateway.

Other options include bridging both networks together, using a NAT router between the networks, and other non-straightforward methods.

Comment: I would be careful with connecting 2 different networks. They could be separate for a good reason such as security policy requirements. It can be a serious offense to connect an isolated network to the main network without permission. Otherwise, yeah, simply connecting a second network interface on the laptop to the second network should work fine. Just be sure to ask whoever is in charge before you proceed.

Comment: @FrameHowitzer Agreed, but the OP talks about *my network* and networks not under your control are explicitly off topic here.

Comment: Probably true, I would agree this is not clear enough to be constructive without reworking and is probably off topic.